# Find the first order of an array which has been scrambled up for 5 times

Tags: arrays, algorithm

The original problem is:
'There were n athletes numbered 1 to n stand in a line. The order was determined by the photographer. However, before the photographer could take a shot, some of the athletes left their spots and talk to their fans. The referee warned all of them and told them to go back to the line, but they didn't maintain the original position. The photographer had to take the shot. After the shot,the referee warned all of them and told them to go back to the line in the original order.  Things happen the same for 4 more times. No athletes was warned for more than once. After that, with the 5 picture given, the photographer will find a way to Photoshop the picture into the one with the order he like. The problem is he didn't remember the order. Program to find that order.'

Here is the example test.[image]

I will solve this by going from the 5th to 1st picture, finding the athletes who moved between every shot, mark them, and find the remaining athletes who haven't  been marked.
However, I am stuck here, since we can not find which athletes in the remaining list moved at first place.
I am needing some help. Please.

Comment: If `1` is supposed to be at the first place in the example, why isn't he warned twice (in the second and third picture)?

Comment: I think that your input data is invalid because in the first try already all athlete (all the number changed) moved so it is impossible that 'No athletes was warned for more than once'

Comment: actually, the athlete number 1 is still at the same spot. However, some guy move into the spot before him or from the spot before him to somewhere after. So the order is changed, however his spot remain the same. in the second picture, guys number 2,4,6 move to the spot before him

Comment: Ok, so then what about the pair `1, 3`. There may be at most 2 pictures where they are not adjacent to each other (one where `1` changed its spot and one where `3` changed its spot). But there are three of those pictures.

Comment: sorry guys. I write the question wrong. after every shot the referee told the athletes to go back to the original  order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two athletes A and B, if A is originally on the left of B, then this order will also be maintained in at least 3 photos out of 5, since each of them can move at most once. So we can recover the original relative positions of any pair of these athletes. (From the example, we know 1 must be on the left of 2 because it is so in 3 photos, #1, #4, and #5.)

From this information the original order can be rebuilt. One way is to calculate the relative positions of every pair, and sort the athletes by the number of athletes on their left. (You probably need a more efficient algorithm though.)